# can we show UIPopOver over UIWindow

Tags: iphone, uiwindow, uipopover

I'm working on application where I want show popover in

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

app delegate function but application throwing exception

```
"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'".
```

I'm calling `popOver` like

```
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:self.rootViewController.view.frame inView:self.rootViewController.view  permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

If I change code like

```
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:self.rootViewController.view.frame inView:self.window  permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

the code work fine.
So is it right to show `popOver` in appdelegates window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view isn't presented yet.  That is why it doesn't have a window.  Try adding that code to the root view controller's viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Thanx peter actually there are many views in my app. I m not sure which view will be present at that time so is there any other solution to this problme.

Comment: yes peter it is working but i am not sure is it valid to show popOver like this.